# How to parse http headers in Go

Tags: http, go

I have http response headers shipped in logs from elsewhere. In my log file I have things like :-

```
Date: Fri, 21 Mar 2014 06:45:15 GMT\r\nContent-Encoding: gzip\r\nLast-Modified: Tue, 20 Aug 2013 15:45:41 GMT\r\nServer: nginx/0.8.54\r\nAge: 18884\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nCache-Control: max-age=864000, public\r\nX-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1\r\nTiming-Allow-Origin: *\r\nContent-Length: 14888\r\nExpires: Mon, 31 Mar 2014 06:45:15 GMT\r\n
```

Given the above as string, how go I parse it into Header object as described in net/http . One way would be to split the string myself and map the key, values... But I am looking to avoid doing that by hand and use the standard (or well maintained 3rd party) library to parse it... Any pointers?

Comment: @dystroy it doesn't look like a duplicate to me, could you please elaborate ?

Comment: It's pretty trivial to parse this.  It's just a string of key/value pairs each separated by line breaks.  You may want to roll up your sleeves on this one.

Comment: @ralph-caraveo yes its trivial, but im lazy. I like to own as less code as possible... also the accepted answer also brings in things like canonicalization, etc for free.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The builtin parser is in textproto. You can either use this directly, or add a
fake HTTP request header and use ReadRequest in the http package. Either way
you need to wrap your data into a bufio.Reader, here I'm just assuming we're
starting with a string.

With textproto:

```
logEntry := "Content-Encoding: gzip\r\nLast-Modified: Tue, 20 Aug 2013 15:45:41 GMT\r\nServer: nginx/0.8.54\r\nAge: 18884\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nCache-Control: max-age=864000, public\r\nX-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1\r\nTiming-Allow-Origin: *\r\nContent-Length: 14888\r\nExpires: Mon, 31 Mar 2014 06:45:15 GMT\r\n"

// don't forget to make certain the headers end with a second "\r\n"
reader := bufio.NewReader(strings.NewReader(logEntry + "\r\n"))
tp := textproto.NewReader(reader)

mimeHeader, err := tp.ReadMIMEHeader()
if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
}

// http.Header and textproto.MIMEHeader are both just a map[string][]string
httpHeader := http.Header(mimeHeader)
log.Println(httpHeader)
```

and with http.ReadRequest:

```
logEntry := "Content-Encoding: gzip\r\nLast-Modified: Tue, 20 Aug 2013 15:45:41 GMT\r\nServer: nginx/0.8.54\r\nAge: 18884\r\nVary: Accept-Encoding\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\nCache-Control: max-age=864000, public\r\nX-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1\r\nTiming-Allow-Origin: *\r\nContent-Length: 14888\r\nExpires: Mon, 31 Mar 2014 06:45:15 GMT\r\n"

// we need to make sure to add a fake HTTP header here to make a valid request.
reader := bufio.NewReader(strings.NewReader("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" + logEntry + "\r\n"))

logReq, err := http.ReadRequest(reader)
if err != nil {
   log.Fatal(err)
}

log.Println(logReq.Header)
```

https://golang.org/pkg/net/textproto

Comment: This works for email also since net/mail uses textproto for mime parsing.